# Replacing ODBC MySQL string to SQL Server String in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I have an ODBC Connection string in MySQL in C#:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=TrAudit_SQL;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;";
```

I have changed my database from My SQL to SQL Server and now I only want to change the connection string, not the rest of the code. I have searched for odbc connection string in SQL Server but I have not been successful. Is there any solution to it that I just change this string and my code further could just remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=myServerAddress;
Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword";
```

Try this.